# gdb does not recognise source file until program is run

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

When I run gdb initially, it appears that gdb does not recognize any source files given to it (for the purposes of adding breakpoints), **unless** the program is first run clean, without any break points:

does not work:

`(gdb) break dir1/dir2/filename.cxx:1
No source file named break dir1/dir2/filename.cxx.`

does work:

`(gdb) run
    etc, etc
    ...
    [Thread 0x... (LWP 14348) exited]
    [Thread 0x... (LWP 14347) exited]
    [Thread 0x... (LWP 14335) exited]
    [Inferior 1 (process 14335) exited normally]
(gdb) break dir1/dir2/filename.cxx:1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x...: dir1/dir2/filename.cxx, line 1.`

I have had a quick search on the gdb bug list: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/ 
and it does not appear to be there. Stack Overflow seems similarly empty.

Firstly, would there be any indication as to why this might be happening, (I suspect that the program itself might be the issue. Or perhaps the source files are only "discovered" by gdb by actually running the code)

Secondly, would there be any way of fixing this?

**Note** if you wish to down-vote this question, I would appreciate it if you could please inform me as to why you did so in the comments. Otherwise, I will remain ignorant. Also, please feel free to ask for clarification

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install breakpoint gdb needs to know the offset at executable corresponding to the requested source code position. This offset is retrieved from symbols table. Symbol tables become available when particular executable (or dll) is actually loaded or if gdb is requested to acknowledge it explicitly (with `file` command for example). However it is possible to `preinstall` breakpoint - inform gdb that you want a breakpoint but it will be actually installed in the future when the required symbols table becomes available. In this case you should see something like this:

```
(gdb) break dir1/dir2/filename.cxx:1
No source file named break dir1/dir2/filename.cxx.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

If you don't get this message then you probably have pending breakpoints turned off. You can check this by executing

```
gdb show breakpoint pending
```

and if it is off then you can enable it using

```
gdb set breakpoint pending on (or auto)
```